# I can't find tape device file inside /dev directory

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, storage, scsi, tape

I'm using tape storage drive HP LTO3 1x8 auto-loader which is connected to my server running CentOS. it is detected in CentOS correctly.

#### cat /proc/scsi/scsi

```
 Host: scsi2 Channel: 00 Id: 01 Lun: 00
 Vendor: HP       Model: 1x8 autoloader   Rev: 1.50
 Type:   Medium Changer                   ANSI  SCSI revision: 03
```

#### lsscsi

```
[1:0:0:0]    cd/dvd  NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00  /dev/sr0
[2:0:0:0]    disk    VMware   Virtual disk     1.0   /dev/sda
[2:0:1:0]    mediumx HP       1x8 autoloader   1.50  /dev/sch0
```

***But the tape device file (`st*` or `nst*`) inside the `/dev` directory has not been created.***

I've loaded all the modules

```
Module                  Size   Used by
sym53c8xx              77039   0 
aic7xxx                119025   0 
st                     38660  0
autofs4                26888  3
sunrpc                243758  1
ipt_REJECT              2383  2
nf_conntrack_ipv4       9506  2
nf_defrag_ipv4          1483  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
iptable_filter          2793  1
ip_tables              17831  1 iptable_filter
ip6t_REJECT             4628  2
nf_conntrack_ipv6       8748  2
nf_defrag_ipv6         12182  1 nf_conntrack_ipv6
xt_state                1492  4
nf_conntrack           79453  3 nf_conntrack_ipv4,nf_conntrack_ipv6,xt_state
ip6table_filter         2889  1
ip6_tables             19458  1 ip6table_filter
ipv6                  322029  29 ip6t_REJECT,nf_conntrack_ipv6,nf_defrag_ipv6
ppdev                   8729  0
parport_pc             22978  0
parport                37265  2 ppdev,parport_pc
e1000                 167662  0
microcode             112594  0
vmware_balloon          7199  0
ch                     13503  0
i2c_piix4              12608  0
i2c_core               31276  1 i2c_piix4
sg                     30124  0
shpchp                 33482  0
ext4                  364410  3
mbcache                 8144  1 ext4
jbd2                   88738  1 ext4
sd_mod                 39488  4
crc_t10dif              1541  1 sd_mod
sr_mod                 16228  0
cdrom                  39771  1 sr_mod
mptspi                 17051  12
mptscsih               36732  1 mptspi
mptbase                93845  2 mptspi,mptscsih
scsi_transport_spi     26151  3 sym53c8xx,aic7xxx,mptspi
pata_acpi               3701  0
ata_generic             3837  0
ata_piix               22846  0
dm_mirror              14101  0
dm_region_hash         12170  1 dm_mirror
dm_log                 10122  2 dm_mirror,dm_region_hash
dm_mod                 81500  12 dm_mirror,dm_log
```

#### output of  dmesg | grep scsi

```
scsi0 : ata_piix
scsi1 : ata_piix
scsi 1:0:0:0: CD-ROM            NECVMWar VMware IDE CDR10 1.00 PQ: 0 ANSI: 5
scsi2 : ioc0: LSI53C1030 B0, FwRev=01032920h, Ports=1, MaxQ=128, IRQ=17
scsi 2:0:0:0: Direct-Access     VMware   Virtual disk     1.0  PQ: 0 ANSI: 2
scsi target2:0:0: Beginning Domain Validation
scsi target2:0:0: Domain Validation skipping write tests
scsi target2:0:0: Ending Domain Validation
scsi target2:0:0: FAST-40 WIDE SCSI 80.0 MB/s ST (25 ns, offset 127)
scsi 2:0:1:0: Medium Changer    HP       1x8 autoloader   1.50 PQ: 0 ANSI: 3
scsi target2:0:1: Beginning Domain Validation
sr0: scsi3-mmc drive: 1x/1x writer dvd-ram cd/rw xa/form2 cdda tray
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi CD-ROM sr0
scsi: waiting for bus probes to complete ...
scsi target2:0:1: Ending Domain Validation
scsi target2:0:1: FAST-160 WIDE SCSI 320.0 MB/s DT IU RDSTRM RTI WRFLOW PCOMP (6.25 ns, 
offset 127)
sr 1:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 5
sd 2:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
scsi 2:0:1:0: Attached scsi generic sg2 type 8
ch 2:0:1:0: Attached scsi changer ch0
```

Does anyone face this issue before and find a solution?

Comment: Isn't your device the SCSI changer that appears at the end?

Comment: @vonbrand its my device you can see output of lsscsi but i can't do read and write operation through scsi changer.

Comment: What exact commands have you tried? What results do you get, what did you expect? If this really is some sort of tape changer, perhaps you need some specific command to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Your output shows that there is a tape changer on the bus. It does NOT show that there is a tape drive on the bus.

I've seen similar behavior previously when the drive in the tape library was faulty, or when the entire library was rebooted, and the changer came online before the drive itself.

If that's the same HP library that I'd previously used, drive failure DOES happen like this.

The other alternative is that you also seem to be running under virtualization, and it's not sure if your VM host is passing all the tape devices down to the VM.